# Get polynomial expression without metadata in Sympy

Tags: sympy

With

```py
from sympy import *
f = Poly(x**2 + 2*x - 1, x)
```

we can get f as a polynomial, but how do I get that polynomial as a latex expression?

```py
latex(f)
```

produces

```latex
\operatorname{Poly}{\left( x^{2} + 2 x - 1, x, domain=\mathbb{Z} \right)}
```

when I need just

```latex
x^{2} + 2 x - 1
```

I need to use `Poly` because the expression I'm working with has several variables and I need it in descending powers of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to a regular `Expr`:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
f = Poly(x**2 + 2*x - 1, x)
print(latex(f.as_expr()))
```

Works for me at least.

Comment: Thank you! You could also use `latex(f.as_expr(), mul_symbol=" \times ")` to write the multiplication sign ×: x^2 + 2×x - 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is a disgusting hack, but I came up with

```py
def poly2latex(p):
    s = str(p).split(',')[0].replace('Poly(', '').replace('**','^').replace('*','')
    return s
```

I just can't find anything in the docs to get the poly back as an expression without messing up the order of terms. So unless anyone knows a better way, this will have to do for now!